# Set selected option by option's attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML `Select` element with various options. Each option has an attribute called `label`.

How can I set option as selected by this attribute value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look up the `option` using an [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), then set its [`selected`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#dom-option-selected) property to `true` using [`prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop).

```
$('option[label="the value here"]').prop("selected", true);
```